# Session "OfficeSearchQueryThrottlingSessionQueryProcessingComponent1" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Tags: 2013, search, 2016

Session "OfficeSearchQueryThrottlingSessionQueryProcessingComponent1" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing/Admin

Hi above error is keep coming in eventviewer every 1 min in SharePoint application servers where Search

Answer (score 2):

Based on error code [definition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb/6ab6ca20-b404-41fd-b91a-2ed39e3762ea?redirectedfrom=MSDN),
error **0xC0000035** means STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION, that is, *the object name already exists*.

If your search topology looks ok and search queries are returning expected results, you could ignore this event viewer error.

Using PS commands, as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spenterprisesearchstatus?view=sharepoint-ps), you could further diagnose the health of the search components.

Comment: i fiexed the issue by deleting un wanted second search service application in application server thanks